# Grid View Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, gridview

I have spent 8 hours already on this problem, yeah I know its a lot of time, but I really want to know how to use the gridview from the Visual Studio 2012. I am making a web site with a data grid, and the only thing I need to do is a CRUD, but all has to be in the grid, the data grid has already some pre-state properties, but I don't know how to use them and that is my question. How can one use the  properties, edit, update and delete from the gridview? Also how can I to get the values from the dynamic textboxes that it generates at the time it makes it editible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [YouTube ASP.NET GridView Tutorial series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xb6t8gJm7Io&list=PL6n9fhu94yhW1NryGv6LxX4U4b07T4RlI).

The series is comprised of many parts, scroll through the list and pick out the relevant topics you need for your understanding of what you are trying to achieve with the `GridView` server control.